# 'AnyObject' does not have a member name - when accessing core data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm running two identical sets of code, however, I do not understand why the second set is failing. If I change the line from
`println(result.password)` to `println(result.token)`
I get an error of `'AnyObject' does not have a member named 'token'`

Here is the working code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    var appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    var context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!
    var newUser = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Users", inManagedObjectContext: context) as! NSManagedObject

    newUser.setValue("test-1", forKey: "token")
    context.save(nil)

    var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Users")
    var results = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)

    if results!.count > 0 {
        for result: AnyObject in results! {
            println(result.password)
        }
    } else {
        println("No results")
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

If I change the line to `println(result)` I receive a printout, showing there is an attribute named `token`.

```
<NSManagedObject: 0x7ffa2945c3a0> (entity: Users; id: 0xd000000000040000 <x-coredata://749CCE65-5C4A-45F2-839C-195A94AFCDB6/Users/p1> ; data: <fault>)
<NSManagedObject: 0x7ffa2945c400> (entity: Users; id: 0xd000000000080000 <x-coredata://749CCE65-5C4A-45F2-839C-195A94AFCDB6/Users/p2> ; data: <fault>)
<NSManagedObject: 0x7ffa2945c460> (entity: Users; id: 0xd0000000000c0000 <x-coredata://749CCE65-5C4A-45F2-839C-195A94AFCDB6/Users/p3> ; data: <fault>)
<NSManagedObject: 0x7ffa2964b360> (entity: Users; id: 0xd000000000100000 <x-coredata://749CCE65-5C4A-45F2-839C-195A94AFCDB6/Users/p4> ; data: {
    password = nil;
    token = "test-1";
    username = nil;
})
```

Comment: Well what type of object is result?

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised that even `println(result.password)` works.
The problem is the type of `result`. In your for-in-loop you explicitly tell Swift to provide `result` as an `AnyObject`:

```
for result: AnyObject in results! {
    println(result.password)
}
```

Now [`AnyObject`](http://swiftdoc.org/protocol/AnyObject/) doesn't have any members called `token`, or `password`. Therefore you can't access these properties, even if the object you're storing might be of a type, which has the properties.
You'll hence have to downcast to the desired type, before being able to access those properties.
This could be achieved by omitting `: AnyObject`, assuming that `results` is an array of the desired type.

Comment: Are you saying to do 
- for result in results! { }

Doing so, I receive the same error. Again, password works.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I omitted : AnyObject, however, still receive the same issue. Maybe I don't fully understand your answer.

Comment: you could also try 

        `for result in results! {
            println((result as YOUR_OBJECT).password)
        }`

Comment: exactly. In your question you did not provide what type `results` is, and what type `result` is supposed to be. Therefore you might have to cast `result` to a certain type.
If you provide the types I could edit my answer...

Comment: Everything I'm returning is a string.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I wasn't quite clear:
What type does `context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)` return?  
And what type contains the `password` and `token` properties?

Comment: That's where I'm unsure as well. I'm trying to pull information from core data. Users is just the entity name. Everything in that table is a string. 

Being fairly new, I'm trying to work with the example code, but haven't been able to figure out why it's acting in this manner.

Comment: Ok, so Apple's documentation (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObjectContext/executeFetchRequest:error:) tells us that `executeFetchRequest` returns an `[AnyObject]?`. Therefore you can indeed omit the `: AnyObject`.

Comment: Yes, which I tried, but still get the same result. Password works, but token throws the mentioned error.

Comment: The problem is: I'm not further familiar with `NSManagedObjectContext`. Here's a great reference though: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObjectContext/executeFetchRequest:error:

Comment: Appreciate your help.